# Replacing "," with "." in multiple column values across a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data-table with multiple columns. Some of them are character columns that have numeric measurements/indices that have something like `"12,3"` or `"1,02"` in their values. The decimals have a comma instead.

I would love to loop over each these character/numeric columns and replace the commas with a decimal to further my data preparation for analysis.

I'd love to use `tidyverse` functions and something like `gsub`. Here was one of my many attempts:

```
     chr.cols <- c('Agriculture', 'Industry', 'Service', 'Crops (%)', 'Other (%)', 
          'Arable (%)', 'Phones (per 1000)', 'Net migration', 'Coastline
          (coast/area ratio', 'Pop. Density (per sq. mi.)')

     countries_df <- for(y in colnames(countries)) { 
          gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", x = countries$y)
     }
```

Comment: Please indicate clearly what kind of help you need.

Comment: Fix the problem as you import the data. Most data import functions have alternates or options that let you specify this, like `read.csv2` or `readr::read_csv2`

Answer (score 2):

If we don't do any assignment, the values are not getting replaced.  Create a copy of the original dataset ('countries_df') if we want to preserve the original data and use `[[` instead of `$`

```
countries_df <- countries 
for(y in chr.cols) { 
   countries_df[[y]] <- gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".",
            x = countries_df[[y]])
   }
```

Note that here we are using `[[` instead of `[` so that it would still work for datasets that have `tbl_df` class, `data.table` etc.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to nest two calls to `sub`.  The first call targets the thousands separators, and replaced dot with comma.  Then, a second replacement targets a possible decimal point at the end of the string.

```
val <- "1.234.567,123"
gsub(",(?=\\d{3}$)", ".", gsub("\\.", ",", val), perl=TRUE)

[1] "1,234,567.123"
```

A more ideal solution might be to leverage locale formatting using some R API.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the results of your pattern replacement (`gsub`) back into your dataset (or, for best practice, into a new dataset). Also, the columns names must be called in the `[row, column]` format for avoiding confusion (`data$y` could be your index `y` or the column named `y`).

```
## Duplicating the dataset
countries_modified <- countries

## Looping through the columns
for(y in 1:ncol(countries)) { 
     countries_modified[, y] <- gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", x = countries[, y])
}
```